# How do I activate the TOC button in an Cocoa Help file?

Tags: cocoa

I am building my first help file and so far all is working except one thing:
There is a Table of contents button in the help browser that is deactivated for my help (and so far all 3rd Party help I looked at). 
However it's used in most Apple Apps. It allows you to hide reveal a navigation on the left side of the help page.

I found no documentation about this at all. So I wondered if anyone has figured out how to address this.

Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome on SO! Do you already have some code? If so, edit your question and insert it.

Comment: I simply have a working App.help file. As all help files it's a collection of many html files, I simply have not found a way to designate on html file or a tag in my existing index.html to be the navigation, since Apple always uses json and not html I don't have any example I can learn from (and as I said no documentation).

Answer (score 0):

Taken from https://gist.github.com/mattshepherd/54c66d38be90c2b1acf0

```js
// Disable TOC button
window.HelpViewer.showTOCButton(false);

// Enable TOC button
// If you call this on window load it will flash active for a brief second
// and then disable again. Call if after a delay of 250ms and is works fine
// Not sure what the second variable does yet, but passing false works fine
window.HelpViewer.showTOCButton( true, false, function() {
     //do something to toggle TOC in your webpage
});

// Apple stores the status of the TOC using a window session variable,
// you can use this to keep the TOC open or closed when transitioning
// between pages.
window.sessionStorage.getItem("toc");
```